# Как сделать окно разговора

Tags: html, css, sass

Привет! Мне нужно сделать так как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня сейчас вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить этот маленький треугольник или есть другие способы сделать это?

```css
@import "vars"
@import "fonts"
@import "libs"

ul
    list-style: none

.Companyname
    font-family: $PoiretOne
    color: $white
    font-size: 30px
    margin-top: 74px
    padding-left: 174px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    span:last-child
        color: #C9C9C6
        font-size: 28px 

.first-block
    background-color: $bg-gray
.Top-menu
    display: flex
    margin-top: 75px
    margin-bottom: 0px
    li
        margin-left: 15px
        a
            color: $white
            font-size: 13px
            font-family: $MontserratRegular
            text-decoration: none
            text-transform: uppercase
            &::after
                content: ''
                width: 100%
                height: 2px
                display: block
                background-color: $white
                transform: scale(0)
                transition: all 0.2s 
            &:hover
                    &::after
                        transform: scale(1)
.BigGrayText
    color: $white
    font-size: 50px
    margin-left: 172px
    margin-top: 196px
    font-family: $CabinRegular
    width: 640px
.first-block-2
    background-color: $bg-gray
    button
        background-color: $green
        width: 224px
        height: 56px
        outline: none
        border: none
        color: $white
        text-transform: uppercase
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 13px
        border-radius: 5px 
        margin-top: 60px
.SmallGrayText
    font-size: 15px
    width: 574px
    margin-left: 174px
    font-family: $LatoLight 
    color: $white
    line-height: 32px
    margin-bottom: 272px
.second-block
    background-color: $white
    margin-bottom: 100px
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $CabinRegular
        font-size: 48px
        width: 100%
        color: $very-dark
        text-align: center
        margin-top: 128px
.second-block-2
    margin-left: 176px
    margin-right: 176px
    &-icon
        font-size: 30px
        color: $white
        width: 65px
        height: 65px
        text-align: center
        background-color: $green
        border-radius: 50%
        line-height: 62px
        transform: translateY(-30px)
    &-iconcontainer
        display: flex
        justify-content: center
        width: 100%
    &-main
        display: flex
        justify-content: center
        flex-direction: column
        flex-wrap: wrap
        width: 280px
        border: 1px solid #f2f2f2
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 18px
        color: $very-dark
        text-align: center
        text-transform: uppercase
    &-smalltext
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 16px
        text-align: center
.third-block
    background-color: $gray
    &-bigtext
        font-family: $CabinRegular
        color: $very-dark
        font-size: 48px
        margin-bottom: 40px
        width: 510px
        margin-top: 128px
    &-text
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        color: $text-gray
        font-size: 16px
        margin-bottom: 20px
        width: 510px
    &-button
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 15px
        text-transform: uppercase
        color: $very-dark
        border: 1px solid $very-dark
        border-radius: 5px
        padding: 15px
        width: 232px
        text-align: center
        margin-bottom: 130px
.ClientsBigText
    font-family: $CabinRegular
    font-size: 48px
    color: $very-dark
    text-align: center
    width: 100%
    margin-top: 128px
.ClientMain
    width: 500px
.ClientText
    font-family: $LatoRegular
    font-size: 16px
    color: $text-gray
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2
    padding: 15px
.ClientPerson
    text-align: right
    float: left
    width: 83%
    span:first-child
        font-family: $LatoBold
        font-size: 15px
        color: $very-dark
    span:last-child
        font-family: $LatoRegular
        font-size: 13px
        color: #666666
.ClientImage
    border-radius: 50%
    margin-left: 15px








@import "media"
```

```html
<html lang="ru">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title>CompanyName</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Template Basic Images Start -->
    <meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <!-- Template Basic Images End -->

    <!-- Custom Browsers Color Start -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#FFF">
    <!-- Custom Browsers Color End -->
    <script defer src="libs/fontawesome-free-5.0.8/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row first-block align-items-center">
            <p class="Companyname col-7">
                <span>company</span>
                <span>name</span>
            </p>
            <ul class="col-5 Top-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row first-block-2">
            <p class="BigGrayText">
                We’re here to create your online presense and style
            </p>
            <p class="SmallGrayText">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse mattis orci dapibus risus dignissim, viverra pellentesque
                arcu ullamcorper. Mauris a tincidunt lectus. Proin nec venenatis quam.
                <br>
                <button>start today with us</button>
            </p>

        </div>
        <div class="row second-block">
            <p class="second-block-bigtext">Features you’ll love</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row  second-block-2">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="second-block-2-main">
                    <div class="second-block-2-iconcontainer">
                        <p class="second-block-2-icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="second-block-2-bigtext">Personal touch</p>
                    <p class="second-block-2-smalltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
                        lorem.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="second-block-2-main">
                    <div class="second-block-2-iconcontainer">
                        <p class="second-block-2-icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-flag"></i>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="second-block-2-bigtext">Unique solutions</p>
                    <p class="second-block-2-smalltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
                        lorem.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="second-block-2-main">
                    <div class="second-block-2-iconcontainer">
                        <p class="second-block-2-icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-paint-brush"></i>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="second-block-2-bigtext">Help in promotion</p>
                    <p class="second-block-2-smalltext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
                        lorem.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-end third-block">
            <div class="col-6">
                <p class="third-block-bigtext">Our Short Story</p>
                <p class="third-block-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra lorem.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
                    lorem. .
                </p>
                <br>
                <p class="third-block-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra lorem.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat purus in ferment uectetur tortor id, pharetra
                    lorem.

                </p>
                <br>
                <p class="third-block-button">More about our team</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="ClientsBigText">Our Clients Says</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-5">
                <div class="ClientMain">
                    <p class="ClientText">
                        Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus
                        ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
                        Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
                    </p>
                    <p class="ClientPerson">
                        <span>Joe Doe</span>
                        <br>
                        <span>Creative Deirector at Gmoogle.com</span>
                    </p>
                    <img class="ClientImage" src="img/photo-person.png" alt="ClientPhoto">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: К чему в вопросе, о маленьком треугольнике, столько кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.block__hint {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #777;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.block__hint::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #777;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  bottom: -16px;
  right: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block__hint">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit assumenda illum ab fuga error, exercitationem iure dolorem! Assumenda, enim architecto!
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо,все работает)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 250px auto 0;
  background: #777;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover .block__hint {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  &__hint {
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
    left: -100%;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__hint">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit assumenda illum ab fuga error, exercitationem iure dolorem! Assumenda, enim architecto!
  </div>
</div>
```